# Let $H\leq G$ s.t. whenever 2 elements of $G$ are conjugate then the conjugating element can be chosen from within $H$. Prove that $G'\subseteq H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, derived-subgroup

Question: Let $H\leq G$ such that whenever two elements of $G$ are conjugate, then the conjugating element can be chosen from within $H$.  Prove that $G'\subseteq H$.

Solution: So, if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are conjugate then $g_1=hg_2h^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$.  If we let $a\in G'$, then $a=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ for some $x,y\in G$.  Then, $xa=y^{-1}xy$ and $ay^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}x$.  So, $xa$ and $x$ are conjugate, and $ay^{-1}$ and $y^{-1}$ are conjugate.  So by hypothesis, $y,x\in H$ so $a\in H$.

Does this look okay?  To me, it feels "clunky", but maybe it is just me.

Comment: No there are several mistakes. The statement "if $a \in G'$ then $a = x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ for some $x,y \in G$" is wrong. Secondly, your final statement "by hypothesis $y,x \in H$" is wrong. It is clearly wrong, because $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary elements of $G$ and so you would have proved $H=G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Would you mind helping me out?  Would it be a better start to then, from the first line, get $g_1g_2^{-1}=hg_2h^{-1}g_2^{-1}$, and trying to play with it from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x,y \in G$. Then $x^{-1}$ and $y^{-1}x^{-1}y$ are conjugate so there exists $h \in H$ with $y^{-1}x^{-1}y = h^{-1}x^{-1}h$ and hence $y^{-1}x^{-1}yx = h^{-1}x^{-1}hx$.

Similarly, there exists $k \in H$ with $x^{-1}hx = k^{-1}hk$, so $y^{-1}x^{-1}yx = h^{-1}k^{-1}hk \in H$.

So $H$ is a subgroup containing all commutators, and the commutators generate $G'$, so $G' \le H$.

Answer (score 4):

Derek's answer is definitely quick and nice. Here is another approach, proving that $H$ is normal first.

If $h\in H$ and $g\in G$ then $h$ and $h^g$ are conjugate, so there exists $k\in H$ such that $h^g=h^k\in H$. Thus $H$ is normal in $G$.

Now we prove that $G/H$ is abelian, so $H$ contains $G'$. If $x,y\in G$ then $xyx^{-1}=hyh^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$, yielding
$$HxHy=Hxy=Hxyx^{-1}x=Hhyh^{-1}x=Hyh^{-1}x=HyHh^{-1}Hx=HyHx.$$